# requestAnimationFrame inside another requestAnimationFrame

Tags: javascript, requestanimationframe

Let's say I have *rAF* scheduled inside another *rAF*.

**Component 1:**

```
  update() {
    requestAnimationFrame(() => {
      this.div.addClass('animate1');
      component2.update();
    }
  }
```

**Component 2:**

```
  update() {
    requestAnimationFrame(() => {
      this.div.addClass('animate2');
    }
  }
```

Would it run immediately after the first, or at the next repaint cycle?

Comment: It will run when the next animation frame happens. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame - This usually happens 60 times per second.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the next repaint cycle.
Think of `requestAnimationFrame` as `setTimeout(cb, time_until_next_monitor_refresh)`.

Before your callback is called, at the next monitor refresh, this `time_until_next_monitor_refresh` will be reset again to be a full frame-duration, so there is no way that an animation frame callback scheduled from another animation frame callback fires in the same painting frame*.

Note that that's how the basic requestAnimationFrame loops work anyway, they schedule a callback which will itself schedule a new callback. That this scheduling is done from an other function doesn't change a thing (as long as it's all sync in the callback).

<sup>*<sub>Well, browsers do have [bugs](https://crbug.com/1018120)...</sub></sup>

Answer (score -1):

I guess both the request animation frame would be triggered before the next repaint cycle and it would trigger 2 request animation frame and styling would be applied one after another but just before the next repaint cycle, so suppose if you are changing the color of same div in each rAf then would see a flickering of color.

in the below two picture attach we can clearly see that multiple animation frame is called, animation frame is triggering another raf which then is being called before the next frame

[image: Profiler Image 1]
[image: Profiler Image 2]

Comment: I have added profiler Image in my answer, in which it is clearly visible that nested rAf are being called before the next frame, also you can try the below code sandbox link to see the flickering issue by throttling your system by 6x

[code sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/green-water-7v3rzm?file=/src/App.js)